# exercise 9.3.2 from mmds book

Tags: recommender-system

I am reading this book http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch9.pdf
there is an exercise 9.3.2 a) it says

> Exercise 9.3.2 : In this exercise, we cluster items in the matrix of
>   Fig. 9.8. Do the following steps. (a) Cluster the eight items
>   hierarchically into four clusters. The following method should be used
>   to cluster. Replace all 3’s, 4’s, and 5’s by 1 and replace 1’s, 2’s,
>   and blanks by 0. use the Jaccard distance to measure the distance
>   between the resulting column vectors. For clusters of more than one
>   element, take the distance between clusters to be the minimum distance
>   between pairs of elements, one from each cluster.

I am not able to understand how clustering is done?If I replace all 3,4,5 with 1 and 1,2, with 0 I am left with a matrix

```
  a b c d e f g h
A 1 1   1 0   1 0
B   1 1 1 0 0 0
C 0   0 1   1 1 1
```

What is meant by cluster formation here? How do I solve this exercise or any solution available online please give a link.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the non-zero values is meant to simplify the matrix, i.e. we only care whether the value is zero or not.

Then you're supposed to calculate the [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) between pairs of columns. For instance between the first two columns you have $|a\cap b|=1$, $|a\cup b|=2$ so the distance is 1/2.

After that you're supposed to apply [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) using the distance. This means progressively grouping elements (here columns) which are close to each other according to the distance.